# Way to convert *grpcpool.ClientConn to *grpc.ClientConn

Tags: go, grpc, connection-pooling, grpc-go

I am working in golang for the first time and am trying to convert a variable of type *grpcpool.ClientConn to *grpc.ClientConn.

I would like to pass the variable to a function that only takes *grpc.ClientConn. I am using a grpc client stub which requires the *grpc.ClientConn type and I am using processout/grpc-go-pool for the grpc pooling library. I looked at the possibility of making use of `Factory` in pool.go, but am pretty stuck since that is a type that returns a *grpc.ClientConn.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might be able to make that conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean the `grpcpool.ClientConn` struct is just:

https://godoc.org/github.com/processout/grpc-go-pool#ClientConn

```
type ClientConn struct {
    *grpc.ClientConn
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
```

So I'm fairly certain you can just do:

```
pool := &grpcPool.ClientConn{} // however you get one of these
SomeFunc(pool.ClientConn)
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/YEzy4Wq8WF9 as an example of getting the embedded struct

Comment: Thank you so much that made me realize that I was thinking about part of the pool.go file incorrectly. I really appreciate your comment!